# Forwarding historic (old) syslog to syslog server

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, log, syslog, rsyslog

We can forward syslogs to syslog server by making the below entry in syslog.conf/rsyslog.conf

```
*.*<space/tab>@<syslog_server_name>:<port_no>
```

However, this only sends new syslogs, which are generated after making this entry. But I want to send old syslogs also that are generated before making this entry. Is there any way to send old/historic syslogs to syslog server?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM was in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/